# Is "find" one of the linking verbs?

Tags: grammar, headlinese, linking-verbs

> He found alive.

This sentence was usually written on newspapers. I want to know "find" whether is a linking verb because following it being an adjective.

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the headline correctly?  It would be find if it looked like "Found alive" or "Soccer team found alive", but "He found alive" seems wrong.

Comment: I find your question very interesting, but your example is ungrammatical.  If you could [edit] your question with an actual example from a newspaper, it would help people write answers.

Answer (score 1):

The style of headline involved here tends to omit small words that a native reader finds easy to restore.   Something like

> Man Found Alive

would be understood to mean

> A man was found alive.

This restored sentence is cast in the passive voice.   An active voice equivalent is easier to examine:

> Someone found a man alive.

The term "linking verb" is reserved for those verbs which **directly** license *subject complements*.   The adjective "alive" is a complement in the active voice statement above, but it is not a subject complement there.   It's an object complement.

There does exist a label which covers this situation.   The verb *to find* is a [complex transitive verb](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780192800879.001.0001/acref-9780192800879-e-255).

Your observation is correct.   Even in the passive voice, *to find* still licenses an optional complement.   When the clause is in the passive voice, that complement is an attribute of the subject.   It seems entirely reasonable to consider the "alive" of "a man was found alive" to be a subject complement.

It is not quite as reasonable to consider *to find* as a linking verb.   On its own, that verb does not license subject complements.   Instead, it is the complete passive-voice construction "was found" that offers this license.   Within this construction, that license is provided by the "was", which by itself *is* a linking verb.

*To be* is a linking verb.   *To find* is a transitive verb, and optionally a complex transitive verb.   Together, they create the passive construction "was found", which promotes the target of its complement to its subject.

The headline in question has a linking construction that's missing its essential linking verb.

Answer (score 0):

English-language newspaper headlines are written in a stylized, almost telegraphic form that's very far from standard English grammar.  If you see

> Lost child found alive.

What that means is

> A lost child was found alive.

The newspaper elided (left out) "A" and "was" to save space.

Comment: *He found alive* would not be found in a headline, however, unless the article is about a person whose name is *He*.

Comment: I want to know "alive" is an adjective why it following "found" being a normal verb. Thanks.